# How to add vector tile in openlayers correctly?

Tags: node.js, gis, openlayers, vector-tiles

My openlayer displays vector tiles in the wrong position. I am using Node.js and adding vector tiles in geojson format in openlayer, But xyz of tile that is  returned in the URL is incorrect, What should I do?

I added tilegrid but it seems to make no difference.

Here is my code:

```
new VectorTileLayer({
    style:styleFunction,
    source:  new VectorTileSource({
    projection:'EPSG:4326',
    url:'http://localhost:3000/FacilityInSpecificTilegeojson x_tile={x}&y_tile={y}&zoom={z}',
    format: new GeoJSON(),
    wrapX:true
  })
}),
```

Comment: Check if the zoom levels are offset,  You may need a custom tileUrlFunction e.g. https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/xyz-esri-4326-512.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can i understand tile function, my xyz tile is the same az osm layer? When I use the example that you said, no response i get without any error but my vector is not shown

Comment: It cannot be the same as OSM if the projection is EPSG:4326

Comment: i want to add vector layer in osm map, my vector layer srid is 4326 what should i do?

Comment: Vector tiles are intended to be displayed in the projection they were designed for.  If the tiles use tile pixel units there is no alternative, but for GeoJSON or TileJSON you could load the tiles into a normal vector layer using a tile strategy customised to convert between projections and handle the differences in resolutions between projections.  I cannot find an example of EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857  but here is one with these EPSG:3857 vector tiles https://codesandbox.io/s/osm-vector-tiles-lo7ct displayed in EPSG:4326 https://codesandbox.io/s/osm-vector-tiles-4326-wk8rp